# Submit charges to Stripe using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am attempting to integrate Stripe Elements with my react app. Below is the js page where I submit my payment form, which I have pieced together from various examples online. When I press submit on my form, I do get a token back, but then the charge never gets created, at least according to my Stripe dashboard.

Thank you in advance,

```
// CheckoutForm.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {injectStripe} from 'react-stripe-elements'
import CardSection from './CardSection'

class CheckoutForm extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    console.log(ev)
    // We don't want to let default form submission happen here, which would refresh the page.
    ev.preventDefault();

    // Within the context of `Elements`, this call to createToken knows which Element to
    // tokenize, since there's only one in this group.
    this.props.stripe.createToken({name: 'Jenny Rosen'}).then(({token}) => {
      console.log('Received Stripe token:', token)
      const stripeTokenHandler = (token) => {
        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        const form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
        const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

        // Submit the form
        form.submit();

        this.props.stripe.charges.create({
          amount: this.props.price,
          currency: "usd",
          description: "irl Map Fine Print",
          source: token,
        }, function(err, charge) {
          // asynchronously called
        });
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form id='stripe-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className='stripe-section'>
          <div className='stripe-row'>
            <label id='stripe-name'>Name</label>
            <input id='stripe-name' type='text' placeholder='Jane Doe'/>
          </div>
          <div className='stripe-row'>
            <label id='stripe-email'>Email</label>
            <input id='stripe-email' type='email' placeholder='janedoe@gmail.com' required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='stripe-section'>
          <div className='stripe-row'>
            <label id='stripe-address'>Address</label>
            <input id='stripe-address' type='text' placeholder='2345 Mission St.'/>
          </div>
          <div className='stripe-row'>
            <label id='stripe-city'>City</label>
            <input id='stripe-city' type='text' placeholder='San Francisco'/>
          </div>
          <div className='stripe-row'>
            <label id='stripe-state'>State</label>
            <input id='stripe-state' type='text' placeholder='CA'/>
          </div>
          <div className='stripe-row'>
            <label id='stripe-zip'>ZIP</label>
            <input id='stripe-zip' type='text' placeholder='94110'/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='stripe-section'>
          <CardSection />
        </div>
        <button>Pay ${this.props.price}</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
```

Comment: Where do you define/import `this.props.stripe.charges.create`? Afaik, this is not a part of react-stripe-elements? `stripe.createToken` is provided by the HOC, so you are able to successfully generate a token as you noted yourself, but in order to create the charge you are probably missing some components here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create Charges client-side with your Publishable Key; you need to do it server-side with your Secret Key (which should never be shared, so it should never be published client side).

You'll need to send along the appropriate details to some server-side code - likely in the form you're submitting there - and create the charge server-side: https://stripe.com/docs/charges